# glVertexAttribPointer stride GL_INVALID_VALUE opengl 3.3

Tags: opengl, c++

I'm experiencing issues similar to described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20564469/opengl-glvertexattribpointer-fails-with-invalid-value-for-stride-bigger-tha), which was never answered. Basicly when I'm calling

```
glVertexAttribPointer
```

with *stride* greater than this exact value: `640`. OpenGL GL_INVALID_VALUE error is raised. According to [documentation](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml) such an arror can be raised in one case:

> GL_INVALID_VALUE is generated if stride is negative.

**Which is obviously not my case.**

In OpenGL 4.4 the maximum value is specified and set to `GL_MAX_VERTEX_ATTRIB_STRIDE` according to [this site](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Specification)

Is there a certain *magic number* in older versions of OpenGL (3.3 in my case) for a maximum vertex stride? Is there any other reason that this function can raise `GL_INVALID_VALUE`?

Comment: Are you sure it's because of the stride? "GL_INVALID_VALUE is generated if index is greater than or equal to GL_MAX_VERTEX_ATTRIBS."

Comment: @Bálint I'm absolutely sure about that. When the stride is lower function is not raising any error.

Comment: It wouldn't surprise me if this was one of those omissions in the spec that was corrected in 4.4; in other words, you're hitting a hardware maximum and the implementation is behaving in the only reasonable way, even if the spec says otherwise.  Earlier OpenGL specs were kind of insane like that, and spec bugs are always possible at any version.